# Resolve the error: The multi-part identifier could not be bound?

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge-statement

I am creating a stored procedure and the final "When not matched" statement is throwing an error for the `tmp.DelDate` and `tmp.DelUser` fields.  The "tmp" table is a User-Defined Table Type and the definition is below the sp code.  99 times out of 100, the problem is a bad alias or other typo.  I've been staring at this and I have to be missing something small.  This last statement is almost identical to the first "When Matched" statement.

```
ALTER Procedure dbo.spInsertUpdateProtocolRiskStrats    
    @riskStratsTable ProtocolRiskStrats READONLY

WITH RECOMPILE

AS 
BEGIN

WITH riskStrats as (
    SELECT ol.StratId,
        ol.LinkType,
        ol.LinkId,
        ol.add_user,
        ol.add_date,
        ol.del_user,
        ol.del_date
    FROM ots_StratTriggerOutcomesLinks ol
    JOIN @riskStratsTable rst on ol.LinkId = rst.LinkId 
    WHERE ol.LinkId = rst.LinkId
    AND ol.LinkType = 2
)

MERGE riskStrats
USING @riskStratsTable as tmp
ON riskStrats.LinkId = tmp.LinkId

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET riskStrats.add_date = tmp.AddDate, 
            riskStrats.add_user = tmp.AddUser,
            del_date = null,
            del_user= null

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (StratId, LinkType, LinkId, add_user, add_date)
    VALUES (tmp.StratId, tmp.LinkType, tmp.LinkId, tmp.AddUser, tmp.AddDate)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    UPDATE SET riskStrats.del_date = tmp.DelDate,
            riskStrats.del_user = tmp.DelUser;

END
```

User Table definition

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ProtocolRiskStrats AS TABLE 
(
    KeyId int null,
    StratId int null,
    LinkType int null,
    LinkId int null,
    AddUser int null,
    AddDate datetime null,
    DelUser int null,
    DelDate datetime null
)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `WHEN [not] Matched` stuff from SQLServer but shouldn't the update statements under it have a `where` to me it seems updating everything for every `when` it enters... also another thing I noticed that you have only 1 semi colon at the last when, is this also correct ?

Comment: 1) I highly recommend using meaningful aliases when using merge, e.g. `target` and `source` or similar - it makes things much clearer. 2) You can't do an update on `NOT MATCHED` because you haven't found a row to update. You can only insert.

Comment: What values do you think should be used for `tmp.DelDate` and `tmp.DelUser` when the merge cannot be matched by the source? As per the [WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN <merge_matched>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql#when-not-matched-by-source-then-merge_matched) documentation... _When no rows are returned by <table_source>, columns in the source table can't be accessed. If the update or delete action specified in the <merge_matched> clause references columns in the source table, error 207 (Invalid column name) is returned._

Comment: `When not matched by source`  will update all the records in target that don't match.  I'm using this same logic in another SP and its working perfectly. Except In that SP I'm doing a delete.  The paragraph that @AlwaysLearning is citing even gives an example of what I am doing at the very end.  I can deal with incorrect logic if I can get past this `can't be bound` error.

Comment: Among other sites, this gives a good example of using `when not matched by source then update`.  About 1/2 way down the page.  https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-merge-statement-overview-and-examples/

Comment: I forgot to add, the error occurs when I execute the SP.

Comment: `When not matched by source` means that there's no row available in the source. In other words `tmp.DelDate` and `tmp.DelUser` are not valid values (they don't exist) and so cannot be used in an update. If you want to do an update in this scenario you'll need to supply constant values, or ones calculated somehow (such as the current date/time for `del_Date`).

Comment: That's it!  I knew it was something simple.  If you repost as an answer I'll give you the "win".  Thanks @AlwaysLearning

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @AlwaysLearning, I was assigning values that couldn't exist because it was a "not matched" condition.  I updated my last statement to use constant values.  I had to add another parameter to pass in user name.  I could have also done a "Top 1" on my TVP but my dev lead didn't like that.

```
    UPDATE SET riskStrats.del_date = GETDATE(),
            riskStrats.del_user = @userName;
```